# How to combine like rows based on substring of one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of parts that looks like this:

| Part | Part Num | Thing1 | Thing2 | Thing3 | Thing4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Door | **101053**22 | abc | abc |  |  |
| Door | **101053**23 | abc | abc |  |  |
| Door | **101053**24 | abc | abc | abc |  |
| Door | **846251**11 | abc | abc |  |  |
| Door | **846251**18 | abc | abc | abc | abc |
| Door | **846251**85 | abc | abc |  |  |
| Door | **568971**01 | abc | abc |  |  |

The part number is always 8 characters. For many parts, the first 6 characters are the same, and the last 2 are different. Lines where the first 6 characters of a part number are the same and that have the same value in Thing1/Thing2/Thing3/Thing4 need to be combined, and the part number becomes 6 characters. Lines where the first 6 characters are unique need to remain unchanged and the part number remains 8 characters. The desired result would look like:

| Part | Part Num | Thing1 | Thing2 | Thing3 | Thing4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Door | 101053 | abc | abc |  |  |
| Door | 10105324 | abc | abc | abc |  |
| Door | 846251 | abc | abc |  |  |
| Door | 84625118 | abc | abc | abc | abc |
| Door | 56897101 | abc | abc |  |  |

I'm thinking I could somehow use `RANK` to assign a value of 1 to the rows where the first 6 characters of Part Num and Thing1/2/3/4 are identical. Unique rows then get rank 2, 3, 4 etc.

Then maybe a `CASE` that looks at the rank, and if it's 1 then do LEFT([Part Num], 6) and else just show the whole value. Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Part]
, 'Part Num' =  CASE WHEN MyRank = '1' THEN LEFT([Part Num], 6) ELSE [Part Num] END
, Thing1
, Thing2
, Thing3
, Thing4
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

If that would work, how can I get the rank? Or else, how can this be done?

Thanks!

EDIT: I think rank can be done with `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT([Part Num], 6) ORDER BY Thing1, Thing2, Thing3, Thing4) as MyRank`

The issue now is that sometimes the unique row becomes rank 1, and the similar rows become rank 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a conditional aggregation using `window functions` will do. Then slap a distinct to unique the result set.

```
select distinct 
       part,
       case when count(*) over (partition by part,left(partnum,6),thing1,thing2,thing3,thing4)>1 
            then left(partnum,6) 
            else partnum end as partnum
       thing1, 
       thing2, 
       thing3, 
       thing4
from my_table
```

Comment: That looks like it works, but one thing I didn't anticipate in the data is when there are 5 parts where the first 6 characters in Part Num are the same and 2 rows match each other, 2 rows match each other but don't match the first 2 rows, and the 5th row is unique. I'll update my question with an example of this

Comment: @JeffBrady Please also include the logic for collapsing/not collapsing them in a single row when that happens

Comment: I'm getting clarification on requirements and will update my original post. Thanks for the help!